# PHP JS submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to develop a submit button with js but as I have a register and a login bn on the same page So, when I press the register, it goes fine but if I press the login, the login uses the register files for example.

```
<form name="as" method="POST" action="loginpro.php">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input style="font-size: 17px" type=button onClick="submitform()" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This is the code that I am using to make the login form and as you can see I call a file with the name loginpro.php where I have the php settings to ask the db the files that I need but when I execute it he is calling regpro.php that is the file that I am using for register take a look.

```
<form name="register" method="POST" action="regpro.php">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Email:
  <input type="text" name="Email" />
  <br />
  <br />
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lname" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input style="font-size: 11px" type=button onClick="submitform()" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use two submit buttons. One for Login and One for Registration.

Comment: Post the code of your function submitform() please

Comment: not sure about your error but it seems you can use two different javascript functions for login and for regestration

Comment: What are you trying? JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be something in your `submitform()` Javascript function since both forms are triggering that function in the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, pass the form name to the function, like below:

```
<input style="font-size: 17px" type=button onclick="submitform('as')" value="Submit"/>
<input style="font-size: 11px" type=button onclick="submitform('register')" value="Submit"/>
```

And in your function:

```
function submitform(form) {
    //will submit the form where the button was clicked from within
    document.forms[form].submit();
}
```

jQuery (**remove** inline event handlers `onclick="submitform()"` from both forms)

```
$("input:button").on("click", function() {

    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    $form.trigger("submit");
    //OR
    //$form[0].submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you give them id so you could call the onclick event for each button or other way you could use jquery like below

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type=button onClick="submitform()" value="Submit"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
             $.post("the php page address goes here like regpro.php",
                 {
                       //here set the paramter
                     'firstname':$("#fname").val().trim(),
                     'lastname':$("#lname").val().trim()
                 }, function(data){
                 data=data.trim();
//you can retrive a data to find that the call is success or not
                   });
         });
 </script>
```

you could do the same with login button

Answer (score 0):

Give different id for different form and use the simple way bellow

```
document.getElementById("your_form_id").submit();
```